# Is there a convex set with that property?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Is there any convex set $A\subset X$,where $X$ is a normed Banach space, such that:

$$int(A)\neq int(\overline{A})$$

?

There is a theorem which says that if $A$ is a convex series-closed (cs-closed) then:

$$int(A)=int(\overline{A})$$

where $int(A)$ is the usual interior of the set $A$.

It was a hope here, but there is not a concrete example: [Are convex sets solid?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2051872/are-convex-sets-solid?rq=1)

Comment: Please, give some context and definitions ("$int$" means interior? $X$ is complete/finite dimensional or separable,...?). The intuitive answer would be "no", have you tried to prove that? You might be interested in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/why-does-a-convex-set-have-the-same-interior-points-as-its-closure).

Comment: I think that there should be an example in an infinite dimensional space

Comment: From your link, it's very easy to derive a concrete example: take $X=C([0,1])$, and $A$ the set of polynomials. Then, $A$ is convex, $\overline{A}=X$ by the Weierstrass approximation theorem, but $A$ has empty interior.

Comment: Interior of $C$ is also empty

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I see!